# GHC heap profiling with -hy - What is * (star)?

Tags: haskell, optimization, profiling

When I profile my program's heap usage with -hy flag like

```
./prog +RTS -hy
```

I often see the constructor `*` in the results, along with other constructors such as `[]` and `Word8`.

What is the type `*` in this context? Is it related to `kinds`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoted from [Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/profiling-and-optimization.html):

> There's also some heap allocated data of unknown type (represented as data of type "*").

And in the [GHC User's Guide](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/prof-heap.html):

> For closures which have function type or unknown/polymorphic type, the string will represent an approximation to the actual type.

So, it means basically that the profiling doesn't have enough information to tell what type it is.