# GHC heap profiling with -hy - What is ->, ->>, ->>>?

Tags: haskell, profiling, ghc, heap-profiling

When I profile my program's heap usage with -hy flag (for type descriptions) like

```
./prog +RTS -hy
```

I often see `->a`, `->>a`, `->>>a` in the results (where `a` is either another type or [`*`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24966628/ghc-heap-profiling-with-hy-what-is-star)). What does this mean?